# pulling multiple entries from a match of two tables

Tags: mysql, eav

I have two tables, attributes and attributes_entries

attributes hold the title and attribute_entries hold the value of that title.

if I do:

```
SELECT attribute_entries.title AS ent_title, 
       attributes.title AS attr_title 
FROM   attribute_entries 
INNER JOIN attributes 
       ON attribute_entries.FK_attribute_id = attributes.id 
WHERE attribute_entries.title = 'ford' 
      AND attributes.title = 'manufacturer'
```

I can get a result of:

```
ent_title | attr_title
ford      | manufacturer
```

if I do another query of:

```
SELECT attribute_entries.title AS ent_title, 
       attributes.title AS attr_title 
FROM   attribute_entries 
INNER JOIN attributes 
      ON attribute_entries.FK_attribute_id = attributes.id 
WHERE attribute_entries.title = 'whatev' 
      AND attributes.title = 'nickname'
```

I get the result of:

```
ent_title | attr_title
whatev    | nickname
whatev    | nickname
```

both of these queries allign with the data I have in there.

so I figured this would work:

```
SELECT attribute_entries.title AS ent_title, 
       attributes.title AS attr_title 
FROM attribute_entries 
INNER JOIN attributes 
      ON attribute_entries.FK_attribute_id = attributes.id 
WHERE attribute_entries.title = 'ford' 
      AND attributes.title = 'manufacturer' 
      AND attribute_entries.title = 'whatev' 
      AND attributes.title = 'nickname'
```

This clearly isn't working.  What is my best approach to get the results in one statement?

Comment: EAV schema pattern is bad enough, but you have made it worse by normalizing the values (eg 'ford').

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about.  Are you saying the way I setup this schema is terrible?  Do you propose anything better or just pointing a finger?  I'd love to learn.

Comment: It's a long story.  I added a tag that leads to other EAV discussions.  Here's my discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have read it and I see that this is the problem I am facing.  I'm just not getting anywhere as to how I can approach this as a query.  I have created another questions with better details as to what I am trying to do.  I did not get much feedback yet.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/how-to-find-an-entry-from-filtering-with-two-associated-tables?noredirect=1#comment469345_238037.  This is my first time handling this.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter using pairs:

```
WHERE (attribute_entries.title = 'ford' AND attributes.title = 'manufacturer')
      OR
      (attribute_entries.title = 'whatev' AND attributes.title = 'nickname')
```

Or you can use IN

```
WHERE attribute_entries.title IN ('ford', 'whatev')
      AND attributes.title IN ('manufacturer', 'nickname')
```

In case you need both conditions true you can use EXISTS:

```
WHERE EXISTS(<your first query>)
      AND
      ExISTS(<your second query>)
```

You can check it :*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=81e91be9501b8655f75287858228a152)*

Comment: thanks 
I edited my query like this:
SELECT attribute_entries.title AS ent_title, 
       attributes.title AS attr_title 
FROM attribute_entries 
INNER JOIN attributes 
      ON attribute_entries.FK_attribute_id = attributes.id 
WHERE (attribute_entries.title = 'ford' AND attributes.title = 'manufacturer')
      AND
      (attribute_entries.title = 'whatev' AND attributes.title = 'nickname')

but it did not give me results

Comment: let me check  it

Comment: It should work using OR

Comment: yes it did.  It is still confusing as you would think AND would be the better flag because you want to pull both, but I guess the logic is get this, or get that if you don't find this and vice versa.  But I've confused myself before with AND and OR in PHP before.

anyways, thank you for sharing your answer

Comment: If you want both (AND) then you should use EXISTS.

Comment: Have a look: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=81e91be9501b8655f75287858228a152

Comment: I see.  thx
So there isn't really a difference between using your suggestion of OR (which worked) and using AND with EXISTS?  different query, same results?

Comment: OR and IN return at least one of them, if you need those results where both conditions are true use EXISTS.

Comment: I have added another question that evolved from this because after testing it did not seem to work anymore.  If you're interested to see my other question.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/how-to-find-an-entry-from-filtering-with-two-associated-tables/238330#238330