# How to find an entry from filtering with two associated tables

Tags: mysql, eav

This questions has spinned off of [another question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225625/pulling-multiple-entries-from-a-match-of-two-tables) I probably did not ask correctly from the get go.

I have some tables, where `attributes` and `attributes_entries` that hold a pair of dynamic values for `products`.

The `user` table (just used as an example):

```
id     name       whatever
22     thanos     big guy
```

The `products` table:

```
id   code    price
659  0H040   99.99
660  0H040   99.99
```

The `attributes` table:

```
id   title           model      model_id
1    nickname        products   659
2    manufacturer    products   659
3    rhod            products   660
4    manufacturer    products   null
5    age             user       null
6    age             user       22
```

The `attribute_entries` table:

```
id     title      FK_attribute_id
1      windstar   1
2      ford       2
3      75.3       3
```

I have to find the `product` that matches the `attributes` and `attribue_entries` a `user` is looking for.

So, if the search filter is `manufacturer=ford&nickname=windstar` and these are found for `product` *659* then provide in data set.

How would I go about doing this?  I have a fiddle with queries from my previous question but I can't seem to get the proper results.

**The desired result** is something along the lines of:

```
attr_title      attr_entry_title    attr_model      attr_model_id
nickname        windstar            products        659
manufacturer    ford                products        659
```

But what I really need is to get the product id that simply has a match of both these value pairs `manufacturer=ford&nickname=windstar`.

Since I do not have a FK association to `products`, I think this is going to be a problem.  I didn't associate the `products` because some attributes are entered globally under a model like `products` or `users`, so when someone enters a `product` or `user` they can see a dynamic input under `attributes` called `manufacturer`, and can enter a value for this to associate it to the model (ex.products).

I think I'm going to have to redo this structure since a reverse lookup of attributes and `attribute_entries` I have no idea how to find its `model id` value that has no association.

Comment: You go about it by first studying EAV, as was suggested in comments to your other question.

Comment: e.g. [eav](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Comment: Show us the desired result.

Comment: I have updated for my desired result

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select
    a.title as 'attr_title',
    ae.title as 'attr_entry_title',
    a.model as 'attr_model',
    p.id as 'attr_model_id'

from
    products p
inner join
    attributes a on a.model_id = p.id
inner join
    attribute_entries ae on ae.FK_attribute_id = a.id
where
    ae.title in('ford','windstar')
```

You might be able to modify the where clause like this to exclude unselected terms:

```
ae.title not in (select title from attribute_entries where title not in ('ford', 'windstar')
```

Comment: this provides a big result of showing me all the entries of prods for just 'ford' or just 'windstar'.  What I am looking for is to only show the results of products that matches an association of both 'windstar' and 'ford' only.  thx for this.  At least I can technically do a find the duplicates of p.id with php, check if its 'windstar' and 'ford' and present the data.. if I don't find any other ideas

Comment: I just modified it to provide a way to exclude unselected terms. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I tried this and it provided the same big results unfortunately.  However I did not know I could do an inner join with p.id = a.model_id since they are not associated with a FK.  thanks

Comment: another approach I though about would be if the results provide duplicates of products.id.  Because if there are duplicated when I query for 'ford' and 'windstar' and it displays multiple products.id I know that product hold 'ford' and 'windstar' or the user entered a duplicate of 'forrd' and 'ford' for instance, which wouldn't be my problem.